# How can I make a UFW rule specific to my home wifi network without changing profiles?

Tags: firewall, ufw

Is there any way to make a UFW rule specific to only one wifi network without having to change profiles?  I want to be able to keep ports open for SSH and SAMBA on my computer while it is connected to my home wifi network (which has its own firewall), but have them closed whenever the computer is connected to any other network (i.e. Starbucks).

Right now, I do this manually by switching between "Home" and "Work" profiles in the GUI, but I've forgotten to do that more than once, so I'm trying to take my forgetfulness out of the equation.

Comment: Silly question, but your Samba and SSH config requires authentication to connect, yes?

Comment: Yes, but an open port on a public network is still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure UFW to allow (or deny) traffic to specific *interfaces*, but not networks. If it’s possible to use a wired connection at home and WiFi when out and about, then you can do something like this:

```
sudo ufw deny ssh on wlan0
sudo ufw deny samba on wlan0
```

<sub>**Note:** Be sure to change `wlan0` to the actual interface where you want to block Samba and SSH.</sub>

Alternatively, it would be possible to write a script that disables SSH and Samba every time your system sleeps and/or shuts down, meaning you would have to remember to start the OpenSSH or Samba service manually before using it.